# Upvote application with django. How to be sure that an user will not vote twice the same content?

Tags: django, voting

I'm writing an application with django. Users can Upvote/downvote contents, but they should not vote the same content more than once.

How can I limit user voting?
I thought I can:

- Check user ip
- Create a cookie where store in an array all the ID of the contents that the user has voted

Anything else?

Thank in advance!

Comment: You could do both, save the IP and remeber with a cookie, which votes an user did. But you shouldn't save the IDs directly in the cookie but a create a session and save the IDs in a list. In addition: check how important this is. If it's very important, you should force an user registration. If it's not important, then ignore that users can do tricks to vote twice.

Comment: If a user is authenticated you can track votes to their userid.